# Postfix failed SPF check

Tags: postfix, spf

I'm using postfix to send mail from my own domain and postfix-policyd-spf-perl to check SPF.

SPF check fail only when I send an email from my own domain to my own domain.

In summary :

- mydomain -> gmail.com (SPF works, gmail can check my SPF)
- gmail.com -> mydomain (SPF works, i can check gmail.com SPF)
- mydomain -> mydomain (SPF fails)

After searching in the log, I found that when I'm sending an email to my own domain the ipaddr sender is the client one and not the server one. If my mail client is not in the company network, the ipaddr is not in a reserved ip address range.

I think that's why SPF fails.

TLS uses let's encrypt certificate. LDAP is used to store users credentials. Dovecot is used as a LDA. OpenDKIM, OpenDMARC and SpamAssassin are used as milters.

They all work (except OpenDMARC because of the SPF).

What conf files do I need to change to make this works ?

main.cf

```
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
local_transport = error:Local Transport Disabled
local_recipient_maps =
alias_maps =
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtputf8_enable = no

smtpd_milters = inet:dkim:8891, inet:dmarc:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:dkim:8891, inet:dmarc:8891

### DELIVERY

virtual_mailbox_domains = $mydomain
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:$config_directory/conf/ldap_users
virtual_transport = lmtp:spam:10025

### SMTP SERVER

## Authentication
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = inet:lda:24

## Restrictions
smtpd_client_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        check_helo_access hash:$config_directory/conf/helo_access,
        permit
smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:$config_directory/conf/ldap_users
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        reject_sender_login_mismatch,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_policy_service unix:private/policy, # SPF check
        check_policy_service inet:lda:7026,       # Quota check
        permit
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes

## Security
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/private/letsencrypt/mydomain/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/letsencrypt/mydomain/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/private/dh.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/letsencrypt/mydomain/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtpd_session_cache
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
policy    unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
  user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the client configured? Is it set to use the server as smtp relay?